# Python : Pearson Correlation Between two (identical / non-identical) arrays is returning out of range value

Tags: python, numpy, pyspark, statistics, pearson-correlation

On calculating correlation between two identical arrays, the correlation which is supposed to be 1, is coming out to be greater than 1. Is there any reason for a correlation value to come out of range of [-1,1]

Im using numpy to calculate the covariance and standard deviation.

```py
import numpy as np

a = [1 , 2 , 3 , 4]
covariance = np.cov(a,a)[0][1]
stddeviation = (np.std(a))
```

```
correlation = covariance / (stddeviation * stddeviation)

covariance = 1.6666666666666665

stddeviation = 1.118033988749895

correlation = 1.333333333333333
```

whereas the range of correlation is [-1,1] so the value above should be below 1.

**Edited** :

When I use a UDF for this on pyspark dataframe with adding bias = True in np.cov() function. I still get correlation beyond the range.

```py
df = sc.parallelize(
    [([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.066, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
      ,[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.02, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
     ) , ([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.411666666666666, 
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
          , [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.01, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
         ) , ([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.2733333333333332, 
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
              , [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.29, 
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])]
).toDF(["array1" , "array2"])
```

```py
@psf.udf (FloatType())
def calc_cov(val1 , val2):
    import numpy as np
    val = np.cov(val1 , val2 , bias = True)[0][1]
    return float(val)

@psf.udf (FloatType())
def calc_std_dev(val1):
    import numpy as np
    val = np.std(val1)
    return float(val)

df = df.withColumn(
    "covariance" , psf.round(calc_cov(psf.col("array1") , psf.col("array2")) , 4)
).withColumn(
    "sd_feat1" , psf.round(calc_std_dev(psf.col("array1")) , 4)
).withColumn(
    "sd_feat2" , psf.round(calc_std_dev(psf.col("array2")) , 4)
).withColumn(
    "correlation" , psf.round(psf.col("covariance") / (psf.col("sd_feat1")*psf.col("sd_feat2")) , 4)
).withColumn(
    "pearson_dist" , psf.round(int(1) - (psf.col("correlation")) , 4)
)
```

When you run the above snippet, you will notice that the covariance for these arrays are coming out to be greater than 1.

Comment: In the updated example, those errors are entirely due to propagation of the errors being introduced by the rounding ops.

Comment: @merv The errors are there after removing the rounding off as well.

Comment: when I compute them in numpy with those three pairs, they each satisfy `np.isclose` compared to 1.